# How could I make a c# method more generic?

Tags: c#, csv, stream

I'm exporting my data to CSV, sometimes I'm exporting `Products` or `Prices` and sometimes I'm exporting `Customers`.

So right now I have 3 methods for each type, and I would like to own 1 method for example `CSVExport` instead of `ArticlesCSVExport`, `CustomersCSVExport` and so on..

```
public async Task<byte[]> ArticlesCSVExport(Request searchObject)
{
     var columnHeaders = new string[]
              {
                "Article Name",
                "Article Price",
                "Article Type",
                "Status"
               };
     var result = serviceMethod.GetAll(); // returning all articles..
     var articles = (from Article in result
                         select new object[]
                      {        // Could get this values from column headers? 
                                        $"\"{Article.ArticleName}\"",
                                        $"\"{Article.Price}\"",
                                        $"\"{Article.ArticleType}\"",
                                        $"{(Article.Active==true ? "Active" : "Inactive")}",
                      }).ToList();


    var articlesCsv = new StringBuilder();

    articles.ForEach(line =>
    {
        articlesCsv.AppendLine(string.Join(",", line));
    });

    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{string.Join(",", columnHeaders)}\r\n{articlesCsv.ToString()}");

    return buffer;
}
```

I thought about extending parameters to receive maybe list of data for `CSV`, and maybe column headers? but than how could I escape proper value, because property names would be different for each class; maybe read it somehow from `column headers`?

Comment: Since you return bytes, you could use [Serialization (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/). Or you could use the existing [CSV Helper library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/). Writing a CSV is as simple as `using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
{    
    csv.WriteRecords(records);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example, the only thing that would change if the class was `Price` or `Customer` instead of `Article` is this:

```
var articles = (from Article in result
                 select new object[]
              {        // Could get this values from column headers? 
                                $"\"{Article.ArticleName}\"",
                                $"\"{Article.Price}\"",
                                $"\"{Article.ArticleType}\"",
                                $"{(Article.Active==true ? "Active" : "Inactive")}",
              }).ToList();
```

What changes is how you get an `object[]` from whatever the type is - `Article`, `Product`, etc.

It's not clear from the context whether you would want to make the class generic or the method generic. I'll demonstrate with the method, since the method is what you're showing. (It's also not clear where `result` and `columnHeaders` is declared.)

The signature would change to look like this:

```
public async Task<byte[]> ArticlesCSVExport<T>(
    Request searchObject, Func<T, object[]> extractValuesFunction)
```

The generic argument `T` - allows the caller to specify what the type is (again `Article`, `Product`, etc.)

This next argument:

```
Func<T, object[]> extractValuesFunction
```

...represents passing in a function that takes an instance of `T` and returns a `List<object>`. In other words, instead of that code being part of the method, you're passing it as a parameter to the method.

Now you can replace that section of code with:

```
var lineElements = result.Select(item => extractValuesFunction(item)).ToList();
```

or simplify to

```
var lineElements = result.Select(extractValuesFunction).ToList();
```

I named the variable `lineElements` (?) instead of `articles` because now they could be anything, not just articles.

What we're saying is, "For each one of these things, execute this function which will convert it to an array of objects."

All the parts of the method that stay the same regardless of what `T` is are still part of the method. Whatever changes is moved outside of the method and passed in as an argument. Your original method would now look like this:

```
public async Task<byte[]> ArticlesCSVExport<T>(
        Request searchObject, Func<T, object[]> extractValuesFunction)
{
    var lineElements = result.Select(extractValuesFunction).ToList();

    var csv = new StringBuilder();

    lineElements.ForEach(line =>
    {
        csv.AppendLine(string.Join(",", line));
    });

    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{string.Join(",", columnHeaders)}\r\n{csv.ToString()}");

    return buffer;
}
```

(This also assumes that `result` is a collection of `T` instead of a collection of `Article`, but that's unclear because `result` isn't declared in this method.)

Now, instead of having inline code saying how to take an `Article` and return an `object[]`, you'll just execute that function for each item.

Calling the function could look like this:

```
var output = await ArticlesCSVExport<Article>(
    searchObject,
    article =>
        new object[]
        {
            $"\"{article.ArticleName}\"",
            $"\"{article.Price}\"",
            $"\"{article.ArticleType}\"",
            $"{(article.Active == true ? "Active" : "Inactive")}"
        });
```

In that example we're passing in an anonymous function, but we can pass any function that has the correct signature.

Suppose we have a class like this with a static method:

```
public static class CsvFormatFunctions
{
    public static object[] GetArticleValues(Article article)
    {
        return new object[]
        {
            $"\"{article.ArticleName}\"",
            $"\"{article.Price}\"",
            $"\"{article.ArticleType}\"",
            $"{(article.Active == true ? "Active" : "Inactive")}"
        });
    }
}
```

...then we could pass that method as a parameter:

```
var output = await ArticlesCSVExport<Article>(
    searchObject, CsvFormatFunctions.GetArticleValues);
```

Depending on details that I can't see, the class might need to be generic instead of the method. If that's the case then you would just remove the generic argument `<T>` from the method and put it on the class declaration instead.

Comment: thanks a lot for answer I'll try to apply it right now! And there I've posted where I'm getting from column headers and products..  Thanks one more time !!!

Comment: You could also pass the column headers as a service argument. But the part where you make the service call should probably be outside this method. Somewhere else you can call the service and get the objects. This method would have a more limited responsibility - converting objects to CSV, regardless of where they come from. That makes unit testing easier.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use strategy design pattern

```cs
interface IParser
{
    Task<byte[]> Parse(Request searchObject);
}

public class CustomersCSVExport : IParser
{
    public Task<byte[]> Parse(Request searchObject)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public class ArticlesCSVExport : IParser
{
    public async Task<byte[]> Parse(Request searchObject)
    {
        // Defining file headers
            var columnHeaders = new string[]
               {
                "Article Name",
                "Price",
                "Type",
                "Status"
               };

            // Get the data from  Article Service to export/download
            var result = await ArticleService.Get(searchObject);


            // Escaping "," 
            var articles = (from Article in result
                             select new object[]
                          {        // Could get this values from column headers? 
                                            $"\"{Article.ArticleName}\"",
                                            $"\"{Article.Price}\"",
                                            $"\"{Article.ArticleType}\"",
                                            $"{(Article.Active==true ? "Active" : "Inactive")}",
                          }).ToList();

            // Build the file content
            var articlesCsv = new StringBuilder();

            articles.ForEach(line =>
            {
                articlesCsv.AppendLine(string.Join(",", line));
            });

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{string.Join(",", columnHeaders)}\r\n{articlesCsv.ToString()}");
            return buffer;
    }
}

class CsvParser
{
    private IParser _parser;

    public void SetParser(IParser parser)
    {
        _parser = parser;
    }

    public Task<byte[]> Parse(Request searchObject)
    {
        return _parser.Parse(searchObject);
    }
}

class Client{

    void Main()
    {
        var csvParser= new CsvParser();

        csvParser.SetParser(new ArticlesCSVExport());
        var articleResult =csvParser.Parse(new Request());

        csvParser.SetParser(new CustomersCSVExport());
        var customerResult = csvParser.Parse(new Request());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a generic method, that works independendly of the type.
To define what columns are written, and what value is written for an item, you could require an array of column definitions.
Each column definition would contain the header of that column, and the means how to get the value for an item.

Then just build the header line, and for each item the values line.

**Example:**

```cs
public static string ToCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, params (string title, Func<T, string> valueProvider)[] columnDefinitions)
{
    if (items == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(items));
    }

    if (columnDefinitions == null || columnDefinitions.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(columnDefinitions));
    }

    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var cd in columnDefinitions)
    {
        var title = cd.title;
        builder.Append(PrepareCsvValue(cd.title));
        builder.Append(',');
    }

    builder.AppendLine();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        foreach (var cd in columnDefinitions)
        {
            builder.Append(PrepareCsvValue(cd.valueProvider(item)));
            builder.Append(',');
        }

        builder.AppendLine();
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}

private static string PrepareCsvValue(string value)
{
    value = value.Replace("\"", "\"\"");

    if (value.Contains(','))
    {
        value = $"\"{value}\"";
    }

    return value;
}
```

Here is an example on how to use it:

```cs
public static void Example()
{
    var items = new TimeSpan[]
    {
        new TimeSpan(0), 
        new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1), 
        new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 1), 
        new TimeSpan(0, 1, 1, 1),
        new TimeSpan(1, 1, 1, 1)
    };

    var csvText = items.ToCsv(
        ("Days", ts => ts.Days.ToString()),
        ("Hours", ts => ts.Hours.ToString()),
        ("Minutes", ts => ts.Minutes.ToString()),
        ("Seconds", ts => ts.Seconds.ToString()));

    // Do something with the csv text.
}
```

This is just to get the csv text.
You can create another method that also exports it to a file, using the first method.

**Note:**
I used named types for the column definitions.
That makes for a nice formating in the method call, but can be confusing to some.
You can find more information on named tuples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples).

**Note 2:**
I added code that handles special characters inside values.
As per specification, values may use delimiters, if they are surounded by the " character.
Existing " characters need to be escaped with another ", thus (a"b -> a""b).

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if you can parse using expressions. The mapping can be supplied by the user as mentioned in the example here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/685310/Simple-and-Fast-CSV-Library-in-Csharp